# Can a defaulted template type be universal reference?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, reference, universal-reference

In the following, is `&&` a universal reference ?

```
template <class Function = std::greater<int> > void f(Function&& f = Function());
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The term `universal reference` is a made up term by Scott Meyers to make a distinction between normal rvalue references, i.e. `int&&` and rvalue references in template code, i.e. `T&&`. This is important because of the reference collapsing rules that come into play with template code, so this term is used to aid in teaching. The reason it is called a `unversal reference` is because it can bind to anything.

Just keep in mind that there is no such thing as a `universal reference` in the C++ language, `Function&&` is a **rvalue reference** as far as the language is concerned. However, yes, in Scott Meyer's made up terminology, `Function&&` is a `universal reference` in your example.

Comment: +1 It is almost like we were typing at the same time off of the same script.  Well done.

Comment: Thanks, +1 to you also, since I probably learned most of it from reading your answers on SO.

Comment: @StephenLin:  Keep checking those answers with code!  I did so too with this question.  It is irritating when people don't check their answers with a bit of code.

Answer (score 3):

> is && a universal reference ?

Sort of.  Like the Easter bunny and Santa Claus, there is actually no such thing as a *universal reference* (sorry if I spoiled that for you).  The term *universal reference* does not show up in the standard.  It is term coined by Scott Meyers to describe templated rvalue references when "special deduction rules" are active.

What you show **is** valid code.  And the special deduction rules do apply in this case.  That is, when you pass an lvalue argument `A` to `f`, `Function` will deduce to `A&`.  So by Scott's definition, yes, `Function` is a "universal reference."

Answer (score 1):

[Looks like it](http://ideone.com/Bbfszt), `std::forward<Function>` correctly forwards the argument type when called in your function.